# Wpf FlowDocumentReader column property

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocumentreader

Have one problem with `FlowDocumentReader`. When the "one page view" selected it looks something like that.

[image]

But i want to have only one column, can anyone advise me a solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I've tried to find anything, looks like a column property in FlowDocumentReader, and use google, no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the number of columns by setting a "minimum" column width of the current document. Simply set the [FlowDocument.ColumnWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.columnwidth.aspx) property to some large value to get just one column:

```
reader.Document.ColumnWidth = 1000;
```

The documentation says that

> A value of Double.NaN causes only one column to be displayed,
>   regardless of the page width. The default is Double.NaN.

but apparently the former is not true.

Comment: Just in case `1000` doesn't work, `double.MaxValue` is your friend. It may be overkill but there's no other kill like it.